# Evaluate $P(A^C\cup \!\,B^C)$

Tags: probability

Suppose that A and B are events such that P(A)=1/3, P(B)=1/5  and P(A|B)+P(B|A)=2/3.
Evaluate $P(A^C\cup \!\,B^C)$

P(A)=1/3

P(B)=1/5

$P(A|B)+P(B|A)=\frac{P(A\cap \!\,B)}{P(B)}+\frac{P(B\cap \!\,A)}{P(A)}$
$=\frac{P(A\cap \!\,B)}{1/5}+\frac{P(B\cap \!\,A)}{1/3}$
$=5P(A\cap \!\,B)+3P(B\cap \!\,A)$
$=8P(A\cap \!\,B)=2/3$
$=P(A\cap \!\,B)=1/12$

$P(A^C\cup \!\,B^C)=1-P(A\cap \!\,B)$
$=1-1/12=11/12$

I am really unsure about the last step. Is that legitimate?

Comment: The last step is correct. For $A^c\cup B^c=(A\cap B)^c$. This fac is clear from a Venn Diagram, and is not hard to prove more formally.  There is a bit of not correct writing earlier, when you say that $2/3=\Pr(S\cap B)$. But of course you did not mean to say that.

Comment: $A^c=\neg A$???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all steps are correct.  With the provisio that the step $.. 8P(A∩B)=2/3 =P(A∩B)=1/12$ should be $.. 8P(A∩B)=2/3,\;\therefore P(A∩B)=1/12$.

The last step you did is legitimate.  It's an application of DeMorgan's Law and then the Law of Complements.

$$\begin{align} \mathsf P(A^c\cup B^c) & = \mathsf P((A\cap B)^c) \\ & = 1-\mathsf P(A\cap B)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is correct.
There's a small error at the line above though:
$$\dots=8P(A\cap B)=2/3\color{red}=P(A\cap B)=1/12$$
Just remove the equal sign, separate calculations, and you're good!